# Average length of strings in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a large DataFrame `df` with 50,000+ rows:

```
>> df
                words
0   ["hello","world"]
1  ["what","is","it"]
2      ["yes","dear"]
...
```

I am trying to get the average length of each row and then calculate the average of that. So for the example above, the average for each row would be:

```
0  5
1  2.67
2  3.5
```

And the average of those would be `3.72`. Is there any way of doing this efficiently?

Comment: Did you try the inefficient way?

Comment: Yeah I tried using code snippets from here and looping through each row, but it look WAY too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension for lengths with `np.mean`:

```
s = df['words'].apply(lambda x: np.mean([len(y) for y in x]))
```

Or create `DataFrame` and count `mean` per rows:

```
s = pd.DataFrame(df['words'].tolist()).apply(lambda x: x.str.len()).mean(axis=1)
```

Or use [`Series.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html), get lengths by [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) and last mean per index:

```
s = df['words'].explode().str.len().mean(level=0)
```

---

```
print (s)
0    5.000000
1    2.666667
2    3.500000
Name: words, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Second seems to be the fastest. Removing mine since its surprisingly slow :/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did a very rough test using `time.time()` and the `mean` and `explode`+`str.len` methods ran in the same time (0.48s and 0.47s), while the `np.mean` method ran relatively slower (1.85s).